# Where am I going wrong in my recursive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am working on a learning project that requires me to implement a recursive function that stringifies a passed in object, without using JSON.stringify. I have to consider all data types as parameters that my function will receive, and while I am fine with that, I seem to be getting confused when an array/object is passed, and I call the function on itself to iterate over the object contents.
I am not doing it right and every change I make is impacting other areas I thought I had completed so my frustration is starting to win this battle. Areas I need help on:

1. Output all elements of an array/object in the same way as `JSON.stringify` when I call the function on itself. An example of an issue I see is, if I pass an array like `["SO"]`, I am am getting `[SO]` returned, but it looks like I have that possibility covered!
2. What to do when a function is passed as a param, which is not allowed.

Here is what I have so far. I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
var myJSONRecursiveFunc = function (obj) {

    var stringed = "";
    var result;

    if (Number.isInteger(obj)) {
        return "" + obj + "";
    } else if (obj === null) {
        return "" + null + "";
    } else if (typeof obj === "boolean") {
        return "" + obj + "";
    } else if (typeof obj === "string") {
        return '"' + obj + '"';
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        if (obj.length === 0) {
            return "[" + obj + "]";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (Array.isArray(i)) {
                myJSONRecursiveFunc(i);
            } else {
                stringed += "" + obj[i] + ""
            }
        }
        return result = "[" + stringed + "]";
    } else {
        for (var val in obj) {
            if (typeof val === "object") {
                myJSONRecursiveFunc(val);
            }
            stringed += "" + val + "" + ":" + "" + obj[val] + "" + '';
        }
        return result = "{" + stringed + "}";
    }
};
```

It is far from perfect as I am still learning so please let me know where I can improve along with any help in getting this to work as is.

Comment: `myJSONRecursiveFunc(val);` --- you don't accept a returned value, in multiple branches of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Output all elements of an array/object in the same way as JSON.stringify when I call the function on itself. An example of an issue I see is, if I pass an array like ["SO"], I am am getting [SO] returned, but it looks like I have that possibility covered!

Your recursion of `var val in obj` is only passing in `val`, which is the key of `obj`. You need to call `myJSONRecursiveFunc(obj[val])` in order to get the right result. Additionally, this is true for your array. Your if statement needs to check to see if `obj[i]` is an array, not `i` which would just be an integer. In this case, you need to say:

```
if (Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
  myJSONRecursiveFunc(obj[i])
}
```

> What to do when a function is passed as a param, which is not allowed.

You would need to have a check to see if the function being passed in is a function, with `typeof`, such as: `if (typeof func === function)`

This is a pretty fun exercise. I did this a few months back, and had access to the Underscore library to do so. Here's working code:

```
var stringifyJSON = function(obj) {
  //Strings and null should be addressed here. Strings have quotes inside the string so I can't lump them together with booleans and numbers.
  if (_.isString(obj)){
    return '"' + obj.split('"').join('\\"') + '"';
  }
  if (_.isNull(obj)){
    return 'null';
  }
  //Arrays get a temporary array that their stringified elements get pushed to, and then that temporary array is joined together and concatenated with the brackets that exist within the returned string.
  if (_.isArray(obj)){
    var tempArr = [];
      _.each(obj, function(elem){
        tempArr.push(stringifyJSON(elem));
      });
    return '[' + tempArr.join(',') + ']';
  }
  //Objects get a temporary string to add their stringified data to. Including a check for undefined values and function keys.
  if (_.isObject(obj)){
      var tempArr = [];
      for (var k in obj){
        if (_.isUndefined(obj[k]) || _.isFunction(k)){
          return '{}';
        } else {
          tempArr.push(stringifyJSON(k) + ':' + stringifyJSON(obj[k]));
        }
      }
      return '{' + tempArr.join(', ') + '}';
  }
  //Everything else = booleans, numbers
  else {
    return obj.toString();
  }
};
```

Comment: `if (_.isEmpty(obj)){` is not necessary, the same is the dedicated branch for testing if an object is empty. Just wrap the serialized contents with `[...]`, which may be nothing.

Comment: `removeLastComma` is an ugly solution. Accumulate everything into an array then `join` by `', '` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've incorporated them into the code.

Comment: `return '{}';` is still there :-) Just remove the whole `if (Object.keys(obj).length){`

Comment: Now add escaping for double quotes inside strings so that they were serialized as `"foo\"bar"`

Comment: @rkho Thanks for clarifying. I fully understand what you are saying but for some reason I miss it when i am focused on the larger aspect of the problem, recursion. I do not know why I am having trouble in that area, but as soon as I started reading your answer, I realized what I had done again. Thanks a bunh

Comment: Sorry zerkms, for some reason I'm having a complete brain fart over the escaping thing.

jmcgui05: My favorite resource for learning recursion is the Stanford CS 106B course reader (chapter 5). I believe it's on Scribd.

Comment: @rkho that's easy - for string you must replace every `"` with `\"`

Comment: Thanks again, hope my implementation is somewhat decent :)

Comment: @rkho why `split` + `join` instead of `replace`?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's do this.

### Annotated suggestions

```
function toJSON(obj) {

    // There are people who will disagree with me
    // but I think this variable is declared way too early.
    // It's used in 2 places as a temp variable, so should
    // be declared closer to where it's used.
    // It should also be named more appropriately for how it's used.
    // I used `arrayParts` and `keyValuePairs` instead.

    var stringed = "";

    // As far as I can tell, this variable is never actually
    // used for anything useful.
    // It's always `return result = <thing>`.
    // If you're immediately returning, there's no need to save
    // to a variable.
    var result;

    if (Number.isInteger(obj)) {
        // The initial `"" + <number>` converts to a string.
        // Appending another "" to the end is pointless in
        // all of the below lines.
        return "" + obj + "";
    } else if (obj === null) {
        return "" + null + "";
    } else if (typeof obj === "boolean") {
        return "" + obj + "";
    } else if (typeof obj === "string") {
        return '"' + obj + '"';
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        // If the object is an array with length 0, you
        // already know what it looks like.
        // It's `[]`, so just return that instead of adding
        // the empty array in the middle.
        if (obj.length === 0) {
            return "[" + obj + "]";
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            // In the top of this function, you handle all the
            // different types of objects, so you should recurse and
            // reuse that logic. Checking again here is wasted effort.
            if (Array.isArray(i)) {
                myJSONRecursiveFunc(i);
            } else {
                stringed += "" + obj[i] + ""
            }
        }
        return result = "[" + stringed + "]";
        // A better way to write this section would have
        // looked like this.
        //   var arrayParts = []
        //   for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ){
        //     var stringifiedElement = toJSON( obj[ i ] )
        //     arrayParts.push( stringifiedElement )
        //   }
        //   return '[' + arrayParts.join( ',' ) + ']'
    } else {
        for (var val in obj) {
            // Again, your function's start checks type and handles it.
            // Use that recursively.
            if (typeof val === "object") {
                myJSONRecursiveFunc(val);
            }
            stringed += "" + val + "" + ":" + "" + obj[val] + "" + '';
        }
        return result = "{" + stringed + "}";
        // This section could be rewritten as:
        //   var keyValuePairs = []
        //   for( var key in obj ){
        //     var pair = '"' + key + '":' + toJSON( obj[ key ] )
        //     keyValuePairs.push( pair )
        //   }
        //   return '{' + keyValuePairs.join( ',' ) + '}'
    }
};
```

### Your error

For the record, when you pass in ['SO'] into your function, this is what is happening. The `isArray` block catches the object first.

```
} else if( Array.isArray( obj ) ){
```

Then inside your loop, the `else` block returns `"" + obj[i] + ""`, which converts to `"" + "SO" + ""`, which turns into `"SO"`.

When this is returned, `"[" + "SO" + "]"` turns into `"[SO]"`.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(i)) {
            myJSONRecursiveFunc(i);
        } else {
            stringed += "" + obj[i] + "" // <-- the error
        }
    }
```

### Additional Suggestions

When you loop over obj as an actual object near the end, you do so like this.

```
for( var val in obj ){
  // foo
}
```

*Sidenote: `val` is actually the key, so that's a bit misleading.*

This is an ugly part of Javascript. If the raw `Object` is modified, for example: `Object.prototype.foobar = 5`, then `'foobar':5` will show up in every object in your program. It's worth noting that only developers who are **very** sure what they are doing should ever be doing this, but it is possible.

To make sure this does not break your program, add the following code.

```
for( var key in obj ){
  if( ! obj.hasOwnProperty( key ) ){
    continue
  }
}
```

`obj.hasOwnProperty( <name> )` checks if `obj` has a *direct* property `<name>`. If it does not, then we skip to the next loop iteration with `continue`.

Comment: @zerkms No, I just happened to be adding a largish edit myself. I appreciated the catch about `'"' + key + '":' + toJSON( val )`, so I made sure to add that. If I missed your other improvements, I apologize

Comment: I actually then realized one should `toJSON` the key as well, since the key may contain a double quote character.

Comment: @zerkms That's quite true. However, it seems like very bad practice. For such an unlikely edge case, I feel it would be best not to confuse the fledgling developer more than necessary.